# Starting value error in glm.nb in R

Tags: r, glm

I'm running a negative binomial GLM in R. Running the model with the pooled dataset works just fine, but I'm encountering several warning messages when I attempt to run the same model for some of the smaller un-pooled (separated by animal) datasets. The model contains 12 standardized continuous variables (6 variables, each in linear and quadratic form) . The offset term 'tot' is a numeric vector. Here's a sample of the model; the real one includes all 12 predictors:

```
nb.2 = glm.nb(Count ~ offset(log(tot)) + variable1, data=anim.2)
```

I have run this for several animals and am receiving some or all of the following warnings:

```
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values

glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred 

glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

Numerous searches haven't yielded any clear answers on these warnings. Please advise if more information is needed to answer. Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you're overfitting. how many observations are in your subsets. there are some similar questions [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression) and [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Zero-Inflated-Negative-Binomial-Regression-td4668643.html)

Comment: I see you've already posted at stats. please don't cross-post, this site is for coding questions. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148939/multiple-starting-value-convergence-warnings-when-running-glm-nb-in-r

Comment: Let's see the data (a figure will do).

Comment: @rawr, thanks for your kind suggestion and 10-4 that cross-posting is frowned upon. I decided to crosspost after searching briefly for a rules page and failing to find one, and posted in both because I wasn't sure if my issue was code-based or stats-based.